# OpenCV won't make

Tags: c++, opencv, video, makefile

My OpenCV was installed and working, but when I installed the LibraryFinder plugin for Code::Blocks, it stopped working.
I have removed the plugin and OpenCV, but now, when I try to make it to reinstall i get this error.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
[ 50%] Built target opencv_shape
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lswresample
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lswresample
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to compiling, `ld` is not finding the library `swreasemple`. I believe that this a library from `ffmpeg`.

See if you have this library installed. If you have it, make sure the references to it are correct.

Comment: It is installed, how can i reference it?